# Intersecting two data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames with different columns each

columns in dataframe 1 include

| GID_2 |
| --- |
| MEX.15.1_1 |
| MEX.15.1_2 |
| MEX.15.1_3 |
| MEX.15.1_4 |
| MEX.15.1_5 |
| MEX.15.1_6 |

columns in dataframe 2 include

| ID_MUNICIPIO | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 500 | 200 | 100 |
| 2 | 200 | 300 | 100 |
| 3 | 100 | 600 | 400 |
| 4 | 200 | 400 | 700 |
| 5 | 600 | 100 | 800 |
| 6 | 700 | 100 | 200 |

I want to merge them like this

| GID_2 | X |
| --- | --- |
| MEX.15.1_1 | 500 |
| MEX.15.1_2 | 300 |
| MEX.15.1_3 | 600 |
| MEX.15.1_4 | 700 |
| MEX.15.1_5 | 800 |
| MEX.15.1_6 | 700 |

Sorry if this is a rookie question I am fairly new to R

Comment: What's the logic behind the merge? It's not obvious to me.

Answer (score 2):

The logic is to find the max in each row!
Then we can use `cbind`:

```
cbind(df1, X= apply(df2, 1, max, na.rm=TRUE))

      GID_2   X
1 MEX.15.1_1 500
2 MEX.15.1_2 300
3 MEX.15.1_3 600
4 MEX.15.1_4 700
5 MEX.15.1_5 800
6 MEX.15.1_6 700
```

data:

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(GID_2 = c("MEX.15.1_1", "MEX.15.1_2", "MEX.15.1_3", 
"MEX.15.1_4", "MEX.15.1_5", "MEX.15.1_6")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
> dput(df2)
structure(list(ID_MUNICIPIO = 1:6, B = c(500L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 
600L, 700L), C = c(200L, 300L, 600L, 400L, 100L, 100L), D = c(100L, 
100L, 400L, 700L, 800L, 200L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the intersect function as below:

```
common_rows <- generics::intersect(GID_2, ID_MUNICIPIO)
```

Comment: This will error out. There's no common columns between the two datasets to join on.

Comment: Nor any common values, were you to rename the columns.

Answer (score 1):

More information is clearly needed.  I'll assume that the last digit in GID_2 is the unique key can that can be used for a merge with IDMUNICIPIO in dataset 2.  That is a big assumption.

The pseudo-code to solve this:

1. Create a new column in Dataset1 called "IDMUNICIPIO"
2. "IDMUNICIPIO" will equal the last character in GID_2.
3. Merge Dataset1 and Dataset2 on "IDMUNICIPIO"
4. Find the max in each row of the newly merged data set (see @TarJae suggestion).

At least that's how I think it should go.  But this is predicated on my understanding of GID_2.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).